# QuickBlox server - Using in Android application

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I got the sample Android project from the QuickBlox server and Checked in Android device. I got over all picture of the How to use the Sdk and other API in the Android application. I have some basic query, Please find below and clarify.

1) I can run and test the sample application and able to chat between two user, But whenever I run the application I need to login the user to start a chat, If i commented the login API after first time login, when I click on the any user to chat, it throws exception called Unauthorized user. So is there any way to store the login credential in the App and use it for next time, Since once user logged in they don't need to login again until they manually logged out.

2) All the API required Access token, which is created after initializing the application, I read that It will expired in less than 2 hrs I hope. So is there any API like, the Access token auto created whenever user using the application. Or we need to manually call the Initialize API to get the token. If that's the case How to we know if the Previous token expired?

3) If one user not logged in, If another user trying to send a message to that user they are not receiving messages even after logged in. So how to handle this scenario?

4) Is there any other way apart from Storing the Message in Custom Object for maintaining message history.? Since using this custom object, I need to call the API for storing message details in the Custom Object whenever user send the message, I feel It's costly process, Since I need to manually call the API to add in the custom object, and again I need manually retrieve the data from custom object to display to other user.

Kindly clarify the above questions.

Great Thanks,

Lakshmanan P.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store them in SharedPreferences for Android.
2. Yes, the session has an expiration date and you can check by it when the session is expired. Though we are going to release an update with saving the token in memory and auto renewal in case the app was closed.
3. This is actually XMPP server logic: A sends B (offline) a message. B goes online and receives a message only if A is also online. For more clear logic you can store messages in Custom Objects and upload them from there.
4. Currently you can store history in Custom Objects only. Though we are going to release an update where history and pushes will be stored automatically if the user is offline.

Please feel free to follow [QB blog](http://quickblox.com/blog/) to learn about all updates we make.